# How use retryable jobs in yii 2 queue AMQP Interop (rabbitmq)?

Tags: yii2, rabbitmq, queue

How use `retryable` jobs in `yii` 2 queue `AMQP Interop (rabbitmq)` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is in the [documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/retryable.md).

You can configure "queue" component for your application

```
    'queue' => [
      'class' => \yii\queue\<driver>\Queue::class,
      'ttr' => 5 * 60, // Max time for job execution
      'attempts' => 3, // Max number of attempts
    ],
```

Also, you can override config for a specific Job Model

```
class SomeJob extends BaseObject implements RetryableJobInterface {
  public function execute($queue) {
    //...
  }

  public function getTtr() {
    return 15 * 60;
  }

  public function canRetry($attempt, $error) {
    return ($attempt < 5) && ($error instanceof TemporaryException);
  }
}
```

---

To consume a queue you need [worker(s)](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/worker.md).

Simply you can start a worker with

> ./yii queue/listen

command